# How to multi-thread these two nested loops?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I have two loops iterating over different lists. How can I write a multi-thread python program in a way that all the iterations of inner loop for each element of outer loop happen in different threads?
For example we have two following lists:

```
A = [1,2,3]
B = [4,5,6]
C = []
for i in A:
   for j in B:
      C.append(i+j)
```

Here, we have nine iterations in total. Every time that the first iterator is on one of the A's elements, the other iterator, iterates over all the elements of B. And, this operation repeats three times. I want to know how I can put these three operations in three separated threads.

Comment: Have a look at the [threading library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) or [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) or [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html)

Comment: you need to be aware that with threads you won't get an ordered result (if expected)

Comment: Threading very likely won't speed this code up at all any because the GIL (Global Interpreter Lock)  will prevent both threads from actually running concurrently. It's generally not very helpful for compute-bound tasks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using Numba's prange for these kind of tasks. http://numba.pydata.org/

Vanilla CPython doesn't handle parallel processing well due to GIL.

```
import numba

@numba.njit(parallel=True)
def work():
    A = [1,2,3]
    B = [4,5,6]
    X = [[0 for x in range(0)] for _ in A]
    for idx in numba.prange(len(A)):
       i = A[idx]
       for j in B:
          X[idx].append(i+j)
    C = [0 for x in range(0)]
    for x in X:
       C = C + x
    print(C)

work()
```